# Java Plot Builder

Tags: java, graph, plot

I would like to implement a sort of plot builder (x-y plot, x-time plot, bar not complex plots), where the user defines the generic properties. The results should be some templates that can be used at run time (drag/drop) in another application in which it is decided the data to be plotted. Do you know some tools to be integrated in java or some articles from where to start. I tried to guess if JFreeChart or Gral are able to be used for such things or to pass directly to purchase some product.

Thanks
Marco

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) for this - it's a good library, the charts are pretty flexible and can do all the things you are likely to need from regular plots.

Though you would need to do some extra work to implement "drag/drop" and and special data linking capabilities. I expect this will be the hard part, whatever charting tool you use.